# Java Android: How to launch an Activity from a web server?

Tags: php, android, android-activity, web

I have a web server based on PHP running on my android ,and I have my simple android app which has some activity.Is it possible to start an activity (not the main one) of my app from a PC or android browser as long as both the server and my app are on the same android phone?

In another words, make kind of connection between the server and my app to invoke the wanted Activity?

something like this:

```
<a href="my.Application.Name.ActivityB">click me!</a><p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work solution.

```
exec("am start -n my.Application.Name/my.Application.Name.ActivityB");
```